# How can I send a http request to Ruby on Rails from another application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, lua, coronasdk

currently I'm building an app in Lua using Corona SDK, basically what it does is connect to a database in a Ruby on Rails application.

I'm wondering how to do it, since I can't seem to do something along the lines of:

**/posts/?name=test&title=test&content=test**

```
postData = "name=test&title=bla&content=none"

local params = {}
params.body = postData

network.request( "http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts/", "POST", networkListener, params)
```

This is working except for the parameters sent.

The Ruby on Rails app is using a basic scaffolding, however I'm not sure how to be able to get the Parameters (name,title&content) inside the RoR app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you need to do it through an associative array & json encoding in Lua:

```
local headers = {}
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US"

local posts = {}
posts.name = "test"
posts.title ="bla"
posts.content = "ble"

postData = json.encode(posts)

local params = {}

params.headers = headers
params.body = postData

network.request( "http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts/", "POST", networkListener, params)
```